# Android Studio with opencv for android ndk, libmixed_sample.so

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

So i have looked around everywhere and cant find an answer for this one. Im using android studio with opencv and android ndk to run opencv's sample application called mixed_sample. The app builds all fine, but the application on my phone crashes immediately with "OCV T2 Mixed Processing has stopper" and the below logcat showing it can't find "libmixed_sample.so" which i can confirm IS being generated in "/src/main/libs/(device)/libmixed_sample/so" After heaps of research this is my current setup:

build.gradle:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.opencv.samples.tutorial2"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21

        ndk {
            moduleName "mixed_sample"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs' //set .so files directory to libs
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

// call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        commandLine '/home/alec/libs/android-ndk-r12b/ndk-build', '-C', file('/home/alec/AndroidStudioProjects/OpenCV/openCVTutorial2MixedProcessing/src/main').absolutePath
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:opencv')
}
```

logcat:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
08-12 15:11:39.525 20659-20659/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2 D/OCVSample::Activity: OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!
08-12 15:11:39.525 20659-20659/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2 I/OCVSample::Activity: OpenCV loaded successfully
08-12 15:11:39.525 20659-20659/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-12 15:11:39.535 20659-20659/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: org.opencv.samples.tutorial2, PID: 20659
                                                                              java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libmixed_sample.so"
                                                                                  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                                  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                                  at org.opencv.samples.tutorial2.Tutorial2Activity$1.onManagerConnected(Tutorial2Activity.java:49)
                                                                                  at org.opencv.samples.tutorial2.Tutorial2Activity.onResume(Tutorial2Activity.java:106)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1286)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6987)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4145)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4250)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
08-12 15:11:43.095 20659-20659/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20659 SIG: 9
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

ifdef OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK
  ifneq ("","$(wildcard $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK)/OpenCV.mk)")
    include ${OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK}/OpenCV.mk
  else
    include ${OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
  endif
else
  include /home/alec/libs/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
endif

LOCAL_MODULE    := mixed_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := all
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
```

Comment: You have confirmed that the .so is generated; did you also confirm that it is included in the finished .apk?